# How to stop live-server opening the browser automatically while coding in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a homepage of a website in Kali Linux. So, I installed VS Code and added an extension " Live Server " written by Ritwick Dey. I made HTML file, then CSS and now JavaScript. When I was writing HTML and CSS files, everything was normal with Live Server. But when i started writing JavaScript file, there happened a glitch. Every time, when I take rest after writing some text in `alert(" ");`, the browser automatically opens.
I had used only `alert("some text");`in JavaScript file. After, I made some changes in file by adding some other statements such as `document.getElementById("appname").innerHTML="howdy";` Other statements do not made any disturbance but when I write `alert("some_text");`, the browser automatically opens.

I had enabled **Auto Save** as "afterDelay" and, while writing this question, I gave "off" value to **Auto Save**, it stopped automatically opening the browser but when I save the file, it opens the browser.

I do not want to let the browser open automatically, when I save the file. I want to open the browser manually.

Comment: Do you have the browser running in the background or is it closed entirely? If it is running in the background, the alert could be interpreted as a notification by kali linux and therefore open it up.

Comment: When I started Live Server, it opened the browser. And till then, it (browser) is running in background.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your alert in a function with javascript, make a timer on onclick button so it works when you want it not when server loads